# Multi Dimensional MDX Queries in a DataReader

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, mdx, adomd.net

Please see the code below:

```
 Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

        Try
            Dim con As AdomdConnection = New AdomdConnection("Data Source=localhost;Catalog=Analysis Services Tutorial")

            Dim commandText As String = "select {[Measures].[Sales Amount] AS SalesAmount, [Measures].[Currency Key] as CurrencyKey } On COLUMNS, " & _
    "{[Customer].[Full Name].Members} ON Rows " & _
    ",{[Customer].[Birth Date].Members} ON Pages " & _
    "FROM [Adventure Works DW2012] "

            Dim cmd As AdomdCommand = New AdomdCommand(commandText, con)
            con.Open()
            Dim objDR As AdomdDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection)

            Dim strBuilder As New StringBuilder
            strBuilder.Append("<table>")
            strBuilder.Append("<tr><th>Birth Date</th><th>Full Name</th><th>Currency Key</th><th>Sales Amount</th></tr>")
            Dim intCount As Integer = 0
            While (objDR.Read())
                intCount = intCount + 1
                If intCount = 10 Then
                    Exit While
                Else
                    strBuilder.Append("<tr>")
                    strBuilder.Append("<td>" & objDR(0) & "</td>")
                    strBuilder.Append("<td>" & objDR(1) & "</td>")
                    strBuilder.Append("<td>" & objDR(2) & "</td>")
                    strBuilder.Append("<td>" & objDR(3) & "</td>")
                    strBuilder.Append("</tr>")
                End If
            End While
            strBuilder.Append("</table>")
            Dim str As String = strBuilder.ToString
            MsgBox("got here")

        Catch ex As Exception
            Console.Write(ex.ToString)
        End Try
    End Sub
```

The output is as follows:

[image]

It appears that ADOMD.NET can deal with multi dimensional queries, however the results are flattened.  Is that correct?

The reason I ask is because I have read a few questions on here, which suggests that ADOMD.NET is only capable of displaying two dimensional queries.

Answer (score 1):

Correct. ADOMD.net will only retrieve data in a tabular format.

> As the command runs the query, ADOMD.NET returns the results in the
>   Resultset format, a tabular format as described in the XML for
>   Analysis specification, to flatten the data for the AdomdDataReader
>   object. A tabular format is unusual when querying analytical data
>   considering the variable dimensionality in such data.

[Retrieving Data from the AdomdDataReader](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms123475(v=sql.110).aspx)